# Solving an equation with modular arithmtics

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Consider a machine that operates on the set of real numbers using the following equation:

O = X  × [(I + Y) mod L] − Z,

where I is the input and O is the output of this machine. L is known and it is a public value. X, Y and Z are fixed parameters. How can we determine the fixed parameters (X, Y, Z) using the input/output (I , O)? How many pair of input/output is required to uniquely determine the fixed parameters?

Comment: Any input more than L is unnecessary.

Comment: @LeeNeverGup yes, you are correct. but I am not sure about the value of Y as it can be bigger than L.

Comment: We cannot get Y exactly, as Y and Y+L will give the same result, but we can get [Y mod L].

Comment: @LeeNeverGup How do you find it? Lets assume we determined (X, Y mod L,Z). Then can I re-simulate this machine? I mean if I calculate the output for a specific input, then is it equivalent to the result that I get from this machine?

Comment: Yes, the actual value of Y does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite uncommon to see expression of this kind to be applied to *real* numbers (as opposed to *integers*), but that actually makes the problem more interesting! The solution process is not too much different; even though results might be somewhat surprising.

First of all, it is quite clear that value of $Y$ and $I$ are relevant only modulo $L$; adding or subtracting any integer multiple of $L$ to either of them doesn't affect anything. Thus, we'll assume both to lie in the interval $[0,L)$.

We can now make a few observations:

- If we have two pairs $(I_1,O)$, $(I_2,O)$ with distinct inputs but identical output, the whole expression will evaluate to a constant. In order to see why, equate the expressions applied to $I_1$ and $I_2$ to see that their equality implies $X=0$. In this case, the value of $Y$ remains undetermined (since it doesn't affect anything) and $Z$ is equal to $(-O)$. Thus, from now on, we'll assume that all the outputs are distinct.
- If we restrict $I$ to the interval $0\leq I<(L-Y)$, the sum $I+Y$ stays in the interval $[0,L)$ and the modulo operator doesn't do anything. Thus, the function behaves like a linear one.
  $$O=X\times (I+Y)-Z = XI + (XY-Z)$$
- Once $I$ oversteps the value of $L-Y$, the function becomes linear again, but shifted by a different constant (since the "modulo" operation reduces its argument by $L$):
  $$O=X\times (I+Y-L)-Z=XI + (XY-Z)-XL$$
- A noteworthy point is that $Y$ and $Z$ never appear alone in these expressions, they're always part of the term $(XY-Z)$. This means that even with knowing $X$, we can only find both or find neither.

It is now clear that two inputs are, in general, insufficient to determine the constants; for example, depending on whether both inputs lie on the same side of the breaking point $(L-Y)$ or not, there are at least three different candidates for $X$.

If we have three input-output pairs with $I_1<I_2<I_3$, the situation gets slightly better. All three pairs lie on the same line (equivalent to $X=\frac{O_2-O_1}{I_2-I_1}=\frac{O_3-O_2}{I_3-I_2}$) if and only if they are on the same side of $(L-Y)$ (i.e. all three inputs are smaller than it or all three are greater). If this is the case, we get $X$ directly.

Otherwise, two of the points must lie on one side of the $(L-Y)$ and one on the other. In such case, we have 
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
O_1 & = & XI_1 + (XY - Z) \\
O_3 & = & XI_3 + (XY - Z) - XL \\
\end{array}$$

Combining these two equations determines $X$ uniquely: $X = \frac{O_3-O_1}{I_3-I_1-L}$. The middle pair $(I_2,O_2)$ can then be used to distinguish between the two possible cases and determine whether $(L-Y)$ lies between $I_1$ and $I_2$ or $I_2$ and $I_3$ (and, in case you suspect the pairs given might not actually be produced by function of this form, to distinguish some such cases).

Thus, $X$ can be determined uniquely with three pairs.

Now, the tricky part is $Y$ and $Z$. As mentioned before, they're tied to each other, so in order to determine one, we need to determine the other. There is only one slight problem -- no finite number of inputs can do that! The best we can hope for with $Y$ is an *interval* it lies in; just like in the "two-one" case discussed above. However, since we're dealing with real numbers, the interval can be divided indefinitely. Even the value of $(XY-Z)$ might not be determinable uniquely; if all the given data-points lie on the same line, we don't know whether the breaking point lies to the left or to the right from it. This can be partially helped if you are allowed to make specific queries to the machine, rather than being just given set of input-output pairs; if you ask for the output corresponding to $I=0$, you'll get the value of $(XY-Z)$ for free.

That being said, even though we don't know the actual value of $Y$ and $Z$, we can find the outputs for given inputs, as long as they are in the "unbroken line" parts. For example, if $I_1$ and $I_2$ are found to be on the same side of $(L-Y)$, we can find the output corresponding to any $I\in [I_1,I_2]$.

Comment: That's a beautiful approach. Thank you.

Comment: you mentioned that it is uncommon to see such expressions. why? Is it related to implementation problems, complexity or ...? I want to know your logic and insights.

Comment: @Jolfaei In general, the "modulo" operation is more often seen connected to natural numbers; operating with irrationals tends to range from "difficult" to "impossible". We can either operate symbolically ($\pi$, $\sqrt{2}$, $\pi\bmod \sqrt{2}$, ...) but the resulting expressions tend to grow quite quickly and their evaluation gets slower and slower (unlike integers, where the value of remainder occupies at most as much space as the modulus). Alternatively, we can sacrifice perfect precision and just work with truncated decimals -- but that sends us back to the world of integers.

Comment: @Jolfaei Since you're mentioning implementation issues, I presume you're thinking of computerized implementations. In such cases, the precision is usually limited implicitly by the data-type used; which effectively turns the continuous line back into a finite set of discrete points. In turn, this makes it possible to determine $Y$ (and thus also $Z$) exactly by simple bisection; unlike with reals (or even true rationals), which can be subdivided indefinitely.